# DDMS not display program data on Device

Tags: android, email

Can we view the database of Emails on Device through DDMS ? 
How ever i can see and access the database of SMS on Emulator through DDMS.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2):

Ya you can access nearly everything on the emulator but the same is not true with the device... It provides restricted access... No system files can be accessed... Guess its for our own devices safety... Hence you cant access the Email Database as far as i know!

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

DDMS is designed to work in different way.

https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html